# Magento2 display 502

Tags: magento2

Translation: Recently, my Magento 2.4 website keeps showing a 502 error. I have checked the Nginx server and it seems to be working fine. I also have error logs for PHP.

```
ready to handle connections
[20-Sep-2023 09:22:43] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[20-Sep-2023 09:54:35] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (50), consider raising it、
```

Every time only kill the PHP process, restart PHP-FPM. However, after a while, it was hung again.How can I solve this? Have you ever encountered it?

Answer (score 0):

Check php memory limit, Create  `phpinfo.php` file on the root and write this code.

```
<?php 
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

and run this file using below Url.

URL : https://www.yourwebsite.com/phpinfo.php

Increase PHP parameters values

```
memory_limit 2048M 
max_execution_time 18000 
post_max_size 4096M
max_file_uploads 2000
max_input_time 1000
```